# How to create a custom over lay for a camera in iOS?

Tags: ios, camera

I have a custom camera and I would like the user to take a picture in side of a view. For example, Snapchat has it where the user can take a picture inside of that QR code. What I want to do is the same thing. How do I go about this? Do I photoshop a png? Do I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

To use camera overlay view with custom designed UI (XIB or Storyboard)

first set imagePicker

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
let overlay =     self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OverlayViewCont")
overlay?.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let overlayView = overlay!.view as! OverlayView
overlayView.imagePicker = imagePicker
imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true) {
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
}
```

Comment this if you wanna use default controllers

```
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
```

Then I created an UIView subclass to handle overlayview controlle

```
class OverlayView: UIView { // attache this class to the view in Story board or XIB

    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController?

    @IBAction func capture(sender: AnyObject?){
        imagePicker?.takePicture()
    }
}
```

or you can use AVFoundation and create fully customized camera view. This method you can design it any way you like with out limitation of picker controller.

check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

this is in Objective C but can directly convert it to Swift easily.

Answer (score 0):

Import a png file into your project which will be the overlay for your camera view. Then, on your camera view, set the `cameraOverlayView` property to the image file you imported like so:

```
myCameraView.cameraOverlayView = UIImage(named: "test.png")
```